# How to stop all the running threads and control the number of threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I work with `std:: thread` and I have to create a multithreading application which searches for a file and when the file is found, it should stop all the threads. I tried to use `std:terminate()` for this but my program stops with an error after this. Also I would like to ask, how can I control the number of threads which my function is using?
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include  <conio.h>
#include <string>  
#include <experimental/filesystem>  
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

void SearchFile(const fs::path& pathToShow, string filename,int level=0)
{
    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(pathToShow))
    {
       if (fs::is_directory(entry.status()))
        {
          thread thr(SearchFile, entry.path(), filename,  level + 1);
          thr.join();
        }
        else if (entry.path().filename().u8string() == filename)
        {
            cout << "File was found. Path to file:"<< fs::absolute(entry.path()).u8string() << endl;
            terminate();
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string folder_path;
    cout << "Please input name of folder with full path: " << endl;
    getline(cin, folder_path);
    string filename;
    cout << "Please input filename : "<<endl;
    getline(cin, filename);
    SearchFile(fs::path(folder_path), filename);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The standard doesn't have any facilities for counting the number of "alive" `std::thread` objects, which means you'll have to implement this functionality yourself. However, if you're joining the thread right after starting it, how is that different from an ordinary function call?

Comment: The only safe way to stop a thread is to ask it to stop and wait for it to stop. Anything else can result in an unstable program. Brute force approach: You add a `std::atomic<bool>` to the loop condition iterating through the file list. As soon as one thread finds the file, it sets the bool and all the other threads exit the loop and return as soon as they're done checking whatever item they're working on.

Comment: Recursively creating threads isn't such a good idea. If you have more active threads than processor cores, the threads just start fighting it out for processor time and slow the program down. [Consider a thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool).

Comment: Also, you are not likely to improve much run-time using threads as disk access time will be dominating time particularly for mechanical hard drive where look of seeking might really slow down everything if the head is constantly moving. In most application a single background thread for iterating files might be the best solution while keeping the UI responsive.